# Webpack sources inside vendor js

Tags: webpack

I'm new to webpack and I am trying to convert my angularjs project to it. I am using an online template which has custom js files with direct source mentions in it, like this:

```
$('.login-bg').backstretch([
            "../assets/bg1.jpg",
            "../assets/bg2.jpg",
            "../assets/bg3.jpg"
            ], {
              fade: 1000,
              duration: 8000
            }
        );
```

I am including these js files using the script-loader module like this:

```
import 'script-loader!../assets/scripts/script.js'
```

I would like a solution for webpack to include those images when exporting my project, do you have any idea what is the best way to achieve that?

Also, am I importing these files the best way? I have seen so many *complicated* solutions and this was the easiest and quickest to get working.

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

Found a workaround that I don't really like, but has to work for the time being.
Import the image on the angularjs controller and pass it to the custom script file when loading the page.

**Controller.js**

```
import img1 from "Assets/velona/login/bg1.jpg"
...
Script.init(img1,img2,img3);
```

If someone has a better idea, I am willing to improve this.